# Spel @Value sets null

Tags: spring, properties, spring-el

I try to learn SpEl, and set object fields values from properties. But as result object fields are become null. Here is my code

Config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ExpressiveConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:
/fourthversion/chapter3.placeholders/app.properties")

public class ExpressiveConfig {

@Bean
public
static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
}
```

Class, where I try to set field values:

```
@Component
public class BlankDisc implements CompactDisc {

private String title;
private String artist;

public BlankDisc(@Value("#{systemProperties['disc.title']}") String title,
                 @Value("#{systemProperties['disc.artist']}") String artist) 
{
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;

}
getters and setters
}
```

Here my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExpressiveConfig.class)
public class BlankDiskTest {

@Autowired
private BlankDisc blankDisc;

@Test
public void isBlankDiscNotNull() {
    assertNotNull(blankDisc);
    System.out.println(blankDisc.getTitle());
    System.out.println(blankDisc.getArtist());
}
}
```

Test is passed, object not null, but system prints null, null
Why are the fields values doesn't set?

PS

If I do the same but this way:

```
public BlankDisc(@Value("${disc.title}") String title, 
@Value("${disc.artist}") String artist) {
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;

}
```

then all OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public BlankDisc(@Value("#{systemProperties['disc.title']}") String title,
                 @Value("#{systemProperties['disc.artist']}") String artist) 
{
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;

}
```

Because you initialize the data from system properties, so you need to make sure it is existed

```
@Test
public void isBlankDiscNotNull() {
    assertNotNull(blankDisc);
    assertNotNull(System.getProperty("disc.title"));
    assertNotNull(System.getProperty("disc.artist"));
    assertEquals(blankDisc.getTitle(),System.getProperty("disc.title"));
    assertEquals(blankDisc.getArtist(),System.getProperty("disc.artist"));
    System.out.println(blankDisc.getTitle());
    System.out.println(blankDisc.getArtist());
}
```

Comment: Test fails at assertNotNull(System.getProperty("disc.title"));

Comment: that mean you don't have any variable in system. You must set it

Comment: But how? And why, when I use @Value("${disc.artist}), as I write in PS section, then all works fine? From where in that case program takes values? What is the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is doing?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html , i think you should read about system property firstly. #{systemProperties['disc.title']} String title, it will read value from system with variable "disc.title" and assign value to your variable title. Because of system variable disc.title is null, so your variable is null. You can research how initialize system variable

Comment: You are right. I'm confused with application properties and system properties. Now I understand, why that call of system property returns null. Thank you